# Generating 100, 000 samples of size three from numbers 1 to 20, without replacement

Tags: r, sampling

I am trying to Generate some 100,000 samples of size three from numbers 1 to 20, without replacement, and used the following code in R:

```
s <- sample(N,3,pi<-n*x/sum(x),replace=FALSE)
[1] 12  6 17
```

Now this gave me one sample of size three, but how do I generate 100,000 of them? We also used

```
N<-20 #size of the population we could choose from
n<- 3
x <- runif(N)
pi<-n*x/sum(x)
```

but I do not know what went wrong. Any advice will be greatly appreciated, thank You.

Comment: `replicate(100000, sample(1:20, 3), simplify = FALSE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `lapply` by looping over a sequence

```
N1 <- seq_len(100000)
N <- 20
lapply(N1, function(i) sample(N, size =3, replace=FALSE))
```

Comment: These have all be very useful. Thank You all for all of Your Submissions. Chris Lilly.

Answer (score 4):

Your question inspired me to try to write an implementation of multiple sampling-without-replacement using recursion on sampling-*with*-replacement.

Letting `NS` represent the number of desired samples and `NE` the number of elements to select from the input set for each sample, my idea was that it might be beneficial to try to avoid looping over `NS` `sample()` calls, which would be time-consuming for large `NS`. Instead, we can start by running a single sample call taking `NS` values *with* replacement, and consider that to represent the "first selection" of each sample. Then, for each unique selection, we can reduce the input set (and the probability weighting vector) by the selected element, and recurse until we've reached `NE` levels. By combining each (sub)sample, we can produce a matrix whose rows will each consist of a sample-without-replacement of `NE` values from the input set.

```
samplesNoReplace <- function(NS,set,NE=length(set),prob=NULL) {
    if (NE>1L) {
        inds <- sample(seq_along(set),NS,T,prob);
        uris <- split(seq_len(NS),inds);
        us <- as.integer(names(uris));
        res <- base::matrix(set[inds],NS,NE);
        for (ui in seq_along(uris)) {
            u <- us[ui];
            ris <- uris[[ui]];
            res[ris,-1L] <- samplesNoReplace(length(ris),set[-u],NE-1L,prob[-u]);
        }; ## end for
    } else {
        res <- base::matrix(sample(set,NS,T,if (length(set)==1L) NULL else prob),ncol=1L);
    }; ## end if
    res;
}; ## end samplesNoReplace()
```

Demo:

```
set.seed(10L); samplesNoReplace(10L,1:5,3L,c(10,2,2,2,1));
##       [,1] [,2] [,3]
##  [1,]    1    3    2
##  [2,]    1    4    3
##  [3,]    1    2    4
##  [4,]    3    2    1
##  [5,]    1    3    2
##  [6,]    1    4    2
##  [7,]    1    4    2
##  [8,]    1    2    5
##  [9,]    3    1    2
## [10,]    1    2    5
```

---

## Benchmarking

```
library(microbenchmark);

bgoldst <- function() samplesNoReplace(NS,set,NE,prob);
akrun <- function() { N1 <- seq_len(NS); N <- length(set); lapply(N1, function(i) sample(set, size =NE, replace=FALSE,prob)); };
khashaa <- function() { replicate(NS, sample(set, NE,prob=prob), simplify = FALSE); };
```

---

```
## OP's case (100k samples, smallish set, smaller subset)
set.seed(1L);
NS <- 1e5L; set <- 1:20; NE <- 3L; prob <- runif(length(set));

microbenchmark(times=5L,bgoldst(),akrun(),khashaa());
## Unit: milliseconds
##       expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
##  bgoldst()  40.9888  42.69257  46.33044  46.68856  47.40488  53.8774     5
##    akrun() 547.3142 564.94249 599.96134 625.07602 631.19658 631.2774     5
##  khashaa() 501.1226 521.14871 531.50227 524.65247 549.47600 561.1116     5
```

---

```
## 10k samples, large set, small subset
set.seed(1L);
NS <- 1e4L; set <- 1:1000; NE <- 5L; prob <- runif(length(set));

microbenchmark(times=5L,bgoldst(),akrun(),khashaa());
## Unit: milliseconds
##       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
##  bgoldst() 2716.1904 2722.8242 2756.9302 2731.2763 2753.5668 2860.7935     5
##    akrun()  682.0505  688.3639  691.3169  689.6165  693.9692  702.5842     5
##  khashaa()  684.5865  689.2030  698.8313  693.0822  696.1211  731.1638     5
```

---

```
## 1k samples, large set, large subset
set.seed(1L);
NS <- 1e3L; set <- 1:1000; NE <- 500L; prob <- runif(length(set));

microbenchmark(times=1L,bgoldst(),akrun(),khashaa());
## Unit: milliseconds
##       expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
##  bgoldst() 74478.4313 74478.4313 74478.4313 74478.4313 74478.4313 74478.4313     1
##    akrun()   350.7270   350.7270   350.7270   350.7270   350.7270   350.7270     1
##  khashaa()   353.2574   353.2574   353.2574   353.2574   353.2574   353.2574     1
```

---

```
## 1M samples, small set, necessarily small subset
set.seed(1L);
NS <- 1e6L; set <- 1:4; NE <- 4L; prob <- runif(length(set));

microbenchmark(times=5L,bgoldst(),akrun(),khashaa());
## Unit: milliseconds
##       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
##  bgoldst()  502.0865  519.1875  602.5631  627.6124  648.3831  715.5459     5
##    akrun() 5450.3987 5653.0774 5817.0921 5799.4497 5987.0575 6195.4771     5
##  khashaa() 5301.3673 5667.8592 5683.3805 5744.1461 5824.8801 5878.6497     5
```

---

```
## 10M samples, small set, necessarily small subset
set.seed(1L);
NS <- 1e7L; set <- 1:4; NE <- 4L; prob <- runif(length(set));

microbenchmark(times=1L,bgoldst(),akrun(),khashaa());
## Unit: seconds
##       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
##  bgoldst()  5.023389  5.023389  5.023389  5.023389  5.023389  5.023389     1
##    akrun() 75.891354 75.891354 75.891354 75.891354 75.891354 75.891354     1
##  khashaa() 69.422056 69.422056 69.422056 69.422056 69.422056 69.422056     1
```

---

The pattern is very interesting and, I think, easily explicable. My function outperforms for many samples, small sets, and small subsets, because there are very few recursions required to cover all possible (sub)sample branches, while the looping solutions must iterate and make a `sample()` call for every sample. But my function severely underperforms for fewer samples, large sets, and large subsets, because the looping solutions don't have very many iterations to complete, and the tree of (sub)sample branches grows somewhat exponentially with each new selection. Hence, my function is only appropriate for the case of many samples, small sets, and small subsets, which, incidentally, pretty accurately describes your example use-case.

Of course, even for their most unfavorable timings, the looping solutions still perform decently, within approximately an order of magnitude of my function. Furthermore, many millions of samples of a small subset of a small set is unlikely to be required under any circumstances. So, for the sake of simplicity, I wouldn't consider it unreasonable to ignore this solution entirely, and always use the looping approach.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried both the replicate command and the 1apply, and both give me 100,000 samples of size three for the numbers 1 to 20, which is good, but now I would like to be able to count how often each number appears. I understand that 9, for example, could potentially turn up 100,000 times, being in all 100,000 3-samples, but more likely, it might occur about one twentieth of the time. So if I have 100,000 samples of 3 digits per time, the total count of all numbers should be 300,000, since say for argument's sake R gave me 100,000 nines, where 9 happened to be in every sample, then there are two hundred thousand places left for all the other numbers. I referred to the function as s, and tried 
**count1 <- length(which(s == 2)); count1** , but this said 
**Error in which(s == 1) : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'**, 
but I do not get what that means. How do I ask R to give me an accurate count of all ones, all twos, etc., where I assume their total should sum to 300,000, because we end up with 300,000  numbers in the run. Thanks. Chris Lilly.